# Is there any cocoa-based data visualization library?

Tags: macos, cocoa, data-visualization, business-intelligence, data-analysis

Folks!

Is there any cocoa-based data analytics/visualization library with features like [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try: Core Plot?

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: Cool. :) One question thought: can I make choropleth maps with it? Thanks!